# Embedding Google Calendar to a website the right way (HTML5, that is)

Tags: html, google-calendar-api

I pasted in the link to Google Calendar and it works as supposed to **BUT** VS got sad because the format doesn't follow the HTML5 standard. It truly doesn't, see for yourself.

[Attrocity from the past, inline attributes and other archaic exhibits](https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&showDate=0&showCalendars=0&showTz=0&mode=WEEK&height=400&wkst=2&bgcolor=%23ffffff&src=konrad.viltersten%40gmail.com&color=%23182C57&src=etscb3ui6hjumgqu43ho71m7v8%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23125A12&ctz=Europe%2FStockholm" style=" border-width:0 " width="600" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no")

Can anything be done about it?

Comment: @Rocker - Did you see something erroneous in my question? I see that you've edited it but i can't see what's changed. Sorry about the link - it seems that in the preview it is hidden (just the text in the brackets shows) but here, one can see it all. Ugly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's not such a big issue. Anyway, i've found an other service that integrates with Google Calender and provides much more settings options. It even includes a (limited) possibility to add one owns CSS styling to the embedded calender. And it's sort of free.

The name is "You can book me" and can be found [here](http://b.youcanbook.me/).